# MariaDB copy rows inside table

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I have a very simple table that looks like this:

[image]

It's called `anni_tot` and it has a single field called `anni`. Now, there is another table that looks like this:

[image]

It is called `people_emp`.

---

Now, I want to insert a new field in the table `anni_tot` and so my table now looks like this:

[image]

The task I need to accomplish is: insert in the table `people_emp` a copy of all those data that contain the previous year (previous to 2020 which is 2019) and update the field `anni`. The result should be this:

[image]

In red there is what I should get. Basically, when a new year is added in the table `anni`, I need to make a copy of all the data inside `people_emp` that have the year = year - 1 and update that field to the current year.

I can do this via php but it's pretty hard to maintain. I am trying to do this using a trigger but I am stucked.

---

I can do this but my problem is that I do now know how to retrieve the data of the rows inside people_emp. Any idea?

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER nuovo_anno
AFTER INSERT ON anni
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

 INSERT INTO `people_emp` (`codice`, `nome`, `anno`, `comune`) VALUES ('0', '0', '0', '0');

END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
INSERT INTO people_emp (codice, nome, anno, comune) 
    SELECT pe.codice, pe.nome, 2020, pe.comune
    FROM people_emp pe
    WHERE pe.anno = 2019;
```

This logic can be included in your trigger when a new row is added into the first table.

Comment: I think you have just saved my day

Comment: I thought that he need trigger for automating this :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that something like this would help you

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER nuovo_anno
AFTER INSERT ON anni
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

 INSERT INTO `people_emp` (`codice`, `nome`, `anno`, `comune`) 
    SELECT `codice`, `nome`, new.anni, `comune`
    FROM `people_emp` where anno = new.anni -1; 

END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Yes that works very well and avoids me the mainteance of many php lines!